# Got java "stackoverflow" when join two tables

Tags: java, oop, jpa

I have two java entity classes :

```
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "opportunity_id")
    private OpportunityEntity opportunity;

}
```

and

```
@Table(name = "opportunity")
    public class OpportunityEntity
    {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "opportunity_id")
    private List<UserEntity> users;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mainuser_id")
    private UserEntity mainUser;
    
    }
```

When i search for a list of Users [find users], i've got a "stackoverflow" when mapping `User.opportunity`.

the bug was clear that the opportunity.mainUser refer to User which itself refer to the same opportunity.

Is there another way to design my models ?
For example create a `boolean isMain in User Model` ?

Comment: Can you post stacktrace of exception?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify relationship to `UserEntity` by adding `mappedBy` to annotatation

```
@Table(name = "opportunity")
    public class OpportunityEntity
    {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "opportunity_id")
    private List<UserEntity> users;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="opportunity")
    @JoinColumn(name = "mainuser_id")
    private UserEntity mainUser;
    
    }
```